# Length library which is implemented like chrono for time in C++

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

In C++, there is a library for manipulating quantities involving time. This library is called "chrono". Is there a corresponding library available for lengths? other units?

Comment: Have you looked at boost::units? I'm not clear on exactly what you're looking for but if boost::units isn't it then if you elaborate on how that's not quite it I suspect that will help people to hone in on an answer for you.

Comment: Furlongs? Angstroms? Parsecs? Cubits? What sort of units?

Comment: Build it like `<chrono>` and the choice of units won't matter.  `<chrono>` can handle microfortnights, nanocenturies and gigaseconds. :-)

Comment: @LouisLangholtz: I had not seen boost::units. Thank you.

Comment: I saw Howard's lecture on chrono and the thought about implementing something like duration for other units occurred to me, so I thought that I would ask. I don't have a specific application in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, everyone for your comments.
The video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dExYGSOJzo discusses a new proposal that might become part of c++.